# UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes: crashing iOS7 Devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

For some reason whenever I try and register for remote notifications on an iOS 7 device my app immediately crashes. I'm running the following block of code:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_8_0
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
#else
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
#endif
```

Which should allow me to register for notifications in both iOS 8 and 7 without a hitch (as a number of examples I've already found and looked at suggest) but for whatever reason it still crashes. I've narrowed the crash down to to the third line of code I posted--more specifically the following statement: `[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil];` If I set it to `nil` the app runs perfectly fine, but if I leave the line in it just starts crashing.

I've tried putting a log inside the `respondsToSelector` if statement and the code is definitely not running on iOS 7 devices so I'm somewhat at a loss on what to do.

**EDIT:**
After a few more hours of troubleshooting I finally managed to find a fix. I needed to import **UIKit.framework** into my project under Linked Frameworks and Libraries and set it to **optional**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the `#if`, cause I've never used them, but I have a very similar code that's working, so you could try this:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    // use registerUserNotificationSettings
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

} else {
    // use registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```

If that doesn't work for you, perhaps something else is causing the crash.. ninja-style..

Comment: Yeah, I've tried removing all the `#if` code since I'm only working in Xcode 6  at this point and using exactly what you posted but it's still crashing.

Comment: @ImpurestClub Hm.. strange. Where are you calling this? Inside `didFinishLaunching..`?

Comment: yup! I'm calling it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Comment: @ImpurestClub And you tried copying my exact code and use it? Still nothing?

Comment: Still nothing (using your exact code). I feel like it has to be related to something else.

Comment: @ImpurestClub What kind of crash/error are you getting?